# WordPress loop sort by custom date

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an events custom post type, but would like to sort the posts by date, which is a custom field. I've tried a few methods using meta in the $args but can't get it right. Does anybody have any suggestions?

```
<?php

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'fw-event',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    );

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
        $the_query->the_post();

        global $post;
        $options = fw_get_db_post_option($post->ID, fw()->extensions->get( 'events' )->get_event_option_id());
        $eventbrite = fw_get_db_post_option($post->ID, 'eventbrite');
        $eventlogo = fw_get_db_post_option($post->ID, 'eventlogo');
        $test = fw_get_db_post_option($post->ID, 'event_date_range');

        // Set variables for date
        if ($options['event_children']) {
            foreach($options['event_children'] as $key => $row) :
                $originalDate = $row['event_date_range']['from'];
                $newDate = date("d M, Y", strtotime($originalDate));

                $Day = date("d", strtotime($originalDate));
                $Month = date("M", strtotime($originalDate));
            endforeach;
        }

        ?>

        <?php if (strtotime($newDate) > time() && $options['event_children']) { ?>

        <div class="event-listing">
            <div class="date matchHeightRow">
                <?php if ($options['event_children']) { ?>
                    <?php foreach($options['event_children'] as $key => $row) : ?>
                        <span><?php echo esc_attr__($Day); ?></span>
                        <?php echo esc_attr__($Month); ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
            <div class="content matchHeightRow">
                <aside>
                    <h5>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                            <?php the_title(); ?>
                        </a>
                    </h5>
                    <?php echo limit_words(get_the_excerpt(), '15'); ?>&hellip;
                    <p>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                            <?php echo esc_attr__( 'Find out more &rarr;' , 'wmmc' ); ?>
                        </a>
                    </p>
                </aside>
            </div>
        </div>

    <?php } ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

I'm using variable to split the date as you can see, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Save your date in database using `strtotime()` and you will storage int value of date. And this should work

```
 $args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'fw-event',
    'posts_per_page' => - 1,
    'meta_key'       => 'my_date',
    'order'          => 'DESC',
    'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num',
);
```

This method works fine for me.

If you have date 'from' and date 'to' - save it to different fields.

Comment: Hi, thank you - I cant seem to get this to work, it shows no posts when I use it. I use $originalDate = $row['event_date_range']['from']; to get the from date, which would work well for the order.

Comment: See [WP_Query docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters). You have meta field with date, if you saved date as integer (return by time() or strtotime() functions),you can use orderby => meta_vaue_num.